# How to access specific PHP array object

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, object, if-statement

The following code is passing TM EPO custom product fields (woocommerce addon) to order export plugin, so I can export each field in a separate column in CSV table:

```
var $tm_fields = array( 
        'Day Field'=>['6012beca7979e4.51764573', '6012c0481b1b30.37462970', '6012c0581b1b46.84309510', '6012c05a1b1b51.41167065', '6012c05c1b1b65.99820650', '604a3a296c3179.70414672', '604a3ac46c3183.55870947', '604a3ac66c3193.93047952', '604a3ac96c31a4.57982566', '604a3acb6c31b2.86456982'],
        'Time Field'=>['6012beca7979e4.51764573', '6012c0481b1b30.37462970', '6012c0581b1b46.84309510', '6012c05a1b1b51.41167065', '6012c05c1b1b65.99820650', '604a3a296c3179.70414672', '604a3ac46c3183.55870947', '604a3ac66c3193.93047952', '604a3ac96c31a4.57982566', '604a3acb6c31b2.86456982'],
        'Side Field'=>['6012b57d151e28.97324618', 'pa_side-dish'],
        'Bundle Field'=>['pa_second-dish', 'pa_main-dish'],
    );
    function __construct() {
        add_filter('woe_get_order_product_fields',array($this,'add_product_fields') );
        add_filter('woe_get_order_product_item_meta', array($this,'fill_tm_fields') );
    }
    function add_product_fields($fields) {
        foreach($this->tm_fields as $name=>$element_ids) {
            $fields['tm_field_'.$name] = array('label'=>$name,'colname'=>$name,'checked'=>1);
        }   
        return $fields;
    }
    function format_line($tm_field) {
          
        $a = $tm_field['name'];
        $b = $tm_field['value'];
        
        if ( ($a != 'Side Dish') && ($a != 'pa_side-dish') && ($a != 'pa_main-dish') && ($a != 'pa_second-dish') ) {
            $tm_field = $a . ' - ' . $b; // now $tm_field contains $a and $b           
        } else {
            $tm_field = $b;
        }
    
        return $tm_field;  // can use $tm_field['name'], $tm_field['price'], $tm_field['quantity'], $tm_field['value']     
    }

    function fill_tm_fields($item_meta) {
        // gather TM values to array
        $product_fields = array();
        $product_fields[] = array();
        
        
        // cart items section
        if( isset($item_meta["_tmcartepo_data"])  AND  is_array($tmfields = maybe_unserialize($item_meta["_tmcartepo_data"][0]))  ) {
            foreach($tmfields as $tm_field) {
                $element_id = $tm_field['section'];
                if( !isset($product_fields[$element_id]) ) 
                    $product_fields[$element_id] = array();
                    $product_fields[$element_id][] = $this->format_line($tm_field); 
            }
        }
        
        // make list 
        foreach($product_fields as $element_id=>$values)
            $product_fields[ $element_id ] = join("\n", $values);
        
        // add to item meta 
        foreach($this->tm_fields as $name=>$element_ids) {
            // gather all keys
            $vals = array( );
            foreach($element_ids as $element_id) {
                if( isset($product_fields[$element_id])) 
                    $vals[] = trim($product_fields[$element_id]);
            }
            // it must be array !
            $item_meta['tm_field_'.$name] = array( join("\n", $vals) );
        }   
        return $item_meta;
    }
```

How I can access $tm_fields array label field somewhere (Day Field, Time Field, Side Field, Bundle Field) so I can create an if statement to tell which field meta (name or value) I want to pass, depending on label for example:

```
if ($tm_fields[$name] = "Day Field"){
return $tm_field[name];
} else if ($tm_fields[$name] = "Time Field"){
return $tm_field[value];
}  else if ($tm_fields[$name] = "Side Field"){
return $tm_field[value];
} else if ($tm_fields[$name] = "Bundle Field"){
return $tm_field[value];
}
```

Example Output:

```
Monday (not lunch...) | Lunch (not monday...) Sweet Potato | Sweet Potato, Rocket Salad, Main Dish
```

The main point is that I have 2 arrays (Day Field and Time Field), they contain exactly same fields and data (monday, tuesday are field names, and lunch or dinner are values). I want to return [name] in case of Day Field and [value] in case of Time Field.

Function format_line($tm_field) is just a fast fix which connects both name and value in 1 string e.g. (Monday - Lunch, Tuesday - Dinner etc.)

How output looks now:
[Order export sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEF6g.png)

Dump Data for maybe_unserialize($item_meta["_tmcartepo_data"][0]))

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(24) { ["mode"]=> string(7) "builder" ["cssclass"]=> string(0) "" ["hidelabelincart"]=> string(0) "" ["hidevalueincart"]=> string(0) "" ["hidelabelinorder"]=> string(0) "" ["hidevalueinorder"]=> string(0) "" ["element"]=> array(3) { ["type"]=> string(8) "checkbox" ["rules_type"]=> array(2) { ["Lunch_0"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "percent" } ["<br>Dinner_1"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "percent" } } ["_"]=> array(1) { ["price_type"]=> string(0) "" } } ["name"]=> string(7) "Tuesday" ["value"]=> string(5) "Lunch" ["price"]=> float(9.6) ["section"]=> string(23) "6012c0481b1b30.37462970" ["section_label"]=> string(7) "Tuesday" ["percentcurrenttotal"]=> int(0) ["currencies"]=> array(0) { } ["price_per_currency"]=> array(1) { ["EUR"]=> float(9.6) } ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["multiple"]=> string(1) "1" ["key"]=> string(7) "Lunch_0" ["use_images"]=> string(0) "" ["use_colors"]=> string(0) "" ["changes_product_image"]=> string(0) "" ["imagesp"]=> string(0) "" ["images"]=> string(0) "" ["color"]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> array(10) { ["mode"]=> string(5) "local" ["key"]=> string(12) "sweet-potato" ["is_taxonomy"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(12) "pa_side-dish" ["value"]=> string(12) "Sweet Potato" ["price"]=> float(0) ["section"]=> string(12) "pa_side-dish" ["section_label"]=> string(9) "Side Dish" ["percentcurrenttotal"]=> int(0) ["quantity"]=> int(1) } }
```

Dump Data for $product_fields[$element_id] // cart items section

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Side Dish" } array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "Monday" } array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Side Dish" } array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Wednesday" } array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Side Dish" } array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "Tuesday" } array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "Friday" }
```

Comment: tm_fields is just an array of arrays - you should be able to access it directly with key/index like $tm_fields["Day Time Field"][0] or $tm_fields["Side Field"][1] etc

Comment: Create associative array and  push the value to that array, generate a key to group them like byOrderDate_1147

Comment: As for the output - it will be useful if you show a sample dump of the data from the 
$tmfields = maybe_unserialize($item_meta["_tmcartepo_data"][0]))... line, because it doesn't seem to be really related to the $tm_fields array

Comment: @Dobromir, included some sample dump data for maybe_unserialize($item_meta["_tmcartepo_data"][0])) in question

Comment: Maybe there is a way to search an array using array_search? 
$tm_field['section']; is an array value e.g '6012beca7979e4.51764573', '6012c0481b1b30.37462970' ....

Comment: You already have the "name" and "value" fields separate in the data and you use the format_line function to join them and return them as a string - just return them as an array and use them separately. As for the second question - yes you can use array_search or in_array to check if the value exists

Comment: @Dobromir, the point is that I have 2 arrays (Day Field and Time Field), they contain exactly same fields and data (monday, tuesday are field names, and lunch or dinner are values), I want  format_line function to return [name] in case of Day Field and [value] in case of Time Field. Can u please check the question, there are some edits at the very end, thanks

Comment: This question currently has far more code than it needs to, which makes it hard to follow, and less likely for someone to spend the time to help you. Try to simplify the problem - we don't need to know where your data comes from, so hard-code some sample input data, and the output you want for that sample.

Comment: @IMSoP I see, will update asap